# make client wait for input, client - server

Tags: java, user-interface, server, client

I'm trying to write a very simple client-server program.

Basically as soon as the client connects to the server he gets a login screen where he has to enter a username password and a filename.

My problems are:

1. The client continues with the flow of the code without actually waiting for the input.
2. The server side seems to be stuck at some line and i get a connection reset.

This is the code at the clients side:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) throws JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException
{
    try
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 12345);
        LoginScreen login = new LoginScreen();
        login.open();
        String name = login.getUsername();
        String pass = login.getPassword();
        String log = login.getLogname();
        System.out.println(name + " " + pass + " " + log);
    }
```

this is the LoginScreen

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextField passText;
    private JTextField logText;
    private JLabel userLabel;
    private JLabel passLabel;
    private JLabel logLabel;
    private JButton loginButton;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String logname;

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public String getLogname()
    {
        return logname;
    }

    public LoginScreen()
    {
        super("Login");

        userLabel = new JLabel("username: ");
        passLabel = new JLabel("password: ");
        logLabel = new JLabel("File name: ");

        Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(80,20);
        userText = new JTextField("");
        userText.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
        passText = new JTextField("");
        passText.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
        logText = new JTextField("");
        logText.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);

        loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void open()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel userPanel = new JPanel();
        userPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(userPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel passPanel = new JPanel();
        passPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(passPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel logPanel = new JPanel();
        logPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(logPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();
        loginPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(loginPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);

        userPanel.add(userLabel);
        userPanel.add(userText);
        passPanel.add(passLabel);
        passPanel.add(passText);
        logPanel.add(logLabel);
        logPanel.add(logText);
        loginPanel.add(loginButton);

        pack();

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        username = new String(userText.getText());
        password = new String(passText.getText());
        logname = new String(logText.getText());
    }
}
```

And this is the server

```
try 
{
    Socket client = socket.accept();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    String userPassFile = (String)ois.readObject();
    String[] parts = userPassFile.split("");
    if(AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(parts[0], parts[1]))
    {
        new MMULogService(client,parts[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        oos.writeObject("Incorrect Username / Password");
    }
    client.close();
}
```

it should be noted that before executing the client side, i open the server. 
Currently the output is `null null null` IE - the client side reaches the login.getUsername methods before i clicked "login" on the login screen itself.

And once I close the login screen, I get the error -

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at the line `ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());` in the server.

How do I make the client wait for me to actually hit the login button before doing the get methods? how do i fix the connection reset error?

Comment: I don't see where you use socket in client side ? could you show the rest of your code?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I didn't use the socket yet to transfer data. Just to make a connection to the server. Before transfering the data I wanted to check that the UI (login screen) is working correctly. The rest of the code is irrelevant and doesn't include any client-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can fix your first issue (for the second I don't see your code so I can't help), you need a way to synchronize the main thread and your UI.

So first let the `AWT event dispatching thread` launch your UI as next:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        login.open();
    }
});
```

Or If your use Java 8, simply:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> login.open());
```

Then make your main thread wait before the get methods by making it call a new method like this:

```
login.waitForInputs();
String name = login.getUsername();
...
```

Then in your class `LoginScreen`, the new method will simply make the calling thread wait by doing this:

```
public void waitForInputs() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (this) {
        // Make the current thread waits until a notify or an interrupt
        wait();
    }
}
```

Finally you need to modify the method `actionPerformed` in order to release the main thread when it is ok, by doing something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{
    username = userText.getText();
    password = passText.getText();
    logname = logText.getText();
    // Here you should test if the input values are OK if it is KO do a   
    // return to prevent calling the following code
    synchronized (this) {
        // Release the waiting threads
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

And it is done we have implemented a simple `wait/notify` mechanism to get the input values from the UI before calling the get methods.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed solved the first problem. Regarding the second problem, for some reason the sever's operation seems to be stuck at ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());, as i print "test" just after it and it does nothing.